# Grok filter issue in Logstash

Tags: logstash-grok

I am having a grok issue. I have a log like below

> Login Success [user: jsaver] [Source: 10.110.20.58]

How can I parse the this log with grok filter ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Grok Debugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to test the grok pattern that matches your log.

Here is the grok pattern that matches your log:

```
%{WORD:data} %{WORD:status} \[user: %{USERNAME:username}\] \[Source: %{IP:source_ipaddress}\]
```

Please find the screenshot of the output of the grok debugger:

[image]